# MULTIPLE DOMAIN ON A MAIL SERVER AND WEBMAIL

Tags: postfix, ssl, mail, virtualhost, dovecot

I have a mail server on ubuntu 16.04 with postfix and dovecot and in the same server run roundcube webmail. I access a roundcube webmail with https://webmail.domain1.com (ssl). I need multiple additional domain: webmail.domain2.com, webmail.domain3.com which point to a mail server with https. Which is the best way?

I was trying of create virtual host on my mail server for: webmail.domain2.com, webmail.domain3.com and point to a directory of roundcube but I have a doubts on SSL. The SSL that is used in postfix, dovecot and roundcube it could be the same with my news domain: webmail.domain2.com, webmail.domain3.com.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- All domains should have the same IP-address as `domain1.com` in the DNS zone
- All domains should have `domain1.com` as MX in the DNS zone
- All domains should contain the proper SPF record in the DNS zone
- Postfix should be configured to use virtual domains
- Dovecot needs `location` option to be configured to use `%d/%n` in the path
- Roundcube should be configured to autocomplete the login by the current domain

This is how to setup the mail server. Howtos for webserver you can find anywhere in the net.

Comment: Thanks Kondybas. I already have almost all the points you mention. I'm missing the last point.  How can I get autocomplete login on roundcube?